# If an object created with keyword new, then pushed into vector, do I still need to delete it?

Tags: vector

Question is as the title stated, sample code below:

```
#include <vector>
//I have a rabbit class...
vector<rabbit> rabbitArmy (numOfRabbits,rabbit()); 
rabbit* rabbitOnHeap = new rabbit(); 
rabbitArmy.push_back(*rabbitOnHeap);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Removed salutation: "Thanks in advance!", please don't do it next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone just answer my other question which enlighten me on this one:
Because push_back actually copy the object to the vector, I should still delete rabbitOnHeap.
Moreover I don't need to use the new keyword to add objects to vector at all.

PS: It would be very nice if someone comment "yes, you are right." so I can confirm my answer : )